# Rewriting url for multiple Taxonomies and Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have 2 taxonomies ( genre and artist ) and Custom Post Type ( Lyric )

the url structure i want to get is

CPT: /lyrics/ - archive page for CPT
Artist: /lyrics/artist/ & /lyrics/artist/song-name/
Genre: /lyrics/genre

i've made CPT and Taxonomies using CPT plugin
url is good but on one of taxonomies it's giving me 404 error for page

CPT:

```
    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Lyrics", "sage" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => "lyrics",
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "lyrics/%artis%",
        "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "genre", "artis" ),
    );
```

Genre TAX:

```
 $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Genre", "sage" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'lyrics', 'with_front' => true, ),
        "show_admin_column" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "genre",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
    );
```

Artist TAX:

```
 $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Artist", "sage" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'lyrics', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ),
        "show_admin_column" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "artist",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the same slug of `lyrics` for both your custom taxonomies. WordPress by default cannot share the same slugs for two taxonomies due to WordPress' [rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). Which caters for the default nature of posts, archives, taxonomies, slugs and the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

To prevent your 404 errors you can change your artists array to a unique `slug` like so:

```
$args = array(
        "label" => __( "Artist", "sage" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'artists', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ),
        "show_admin_column" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "artist",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
    );
```

Ensuring you [flush your rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after doing so